# CSS3 Animation is getting problems

Tags: html, css

I am using a small example to demonstrate CSS animations. Though the color is changing but the rotation is not executed. Pls help fix it!

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
p{width:100px;height:100px;background:red;animation-name:peter;animation-duration:5s}
@keyframes peter{
 from{background:orange;}
 to{background:yellow;transform:rotate(180deg;)}
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon is misplaced in `(180deg;)`, should be outside the parenthesis `(180deg);`

```css
    p {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      animation-name: peter;
      animation-duration: 5s
    }
    
    @keyframes peter {
      from {
        background: orange;
      }
      to {
        background: yellow;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `rotate` to `from` and also vendor prefixes to ensure fallback for all browsers.

```
from { 
 background: orange;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);         
 transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
to { 
 background: yellow;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
```